# Xampp on windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, xampp

I have 32 GB Ram on my server. But i can't use the ram. Because my xampp is 32 bit. I didn't find anyting about 64 bit server.

I have web site. I write it Php and Mysql

Can someone help me about this issue ?

Comment: my question is why do you want to use all your RAM ?

Comment: For performance and caching ?@Shobi

Comment: That's not how it works. You are not supposed to install XAMPP in a server. xampp is for local development. Moreover caching is not done by xampp. Its done by softwares like redis, memcached etc.. you will have to install them separately and they will take up RAM as its needed

Comment: Why Xampp is not for production https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297731/why-is-xampp-not-suited-for-production

Comment: Xampp is not local development. Did you see on the website of xampp ? They are not say this app for local development. @Shobi

Comment: As @Shobi already mentioned, XAMPP should not be used on production environments. (see also https://www.quora.com/Is-XAMPP-used-for-life-production-And-Why). If you still want to take it to production, then do it! But you'd still have to use 32-bit build. End of story.

Comment: READ THIS, https://www.apachefriends.org/hosting.html . What are you trying to say? You need to get a 64 bit xampp production server for your server to use up all your RAM? Better Contact Apache friends

Comment: More of a question for http://superuser.com/ IMO

Comment: Windows now has a Linux subsystem (WSL). That allows running apache, mysql (or mariadb) and php natively in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to MySQL, PHP and Apache don't support 64-bit Windows builds and therefore neither XAMPP does. You should be able to run 32-bit XAMPP on 64-bit Windows without any problems though.

You can download XAMPP for Windows [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

Comment: But i don't get best performance on 32 bit system. You know. 32 bit systems using just 4 gb ram.

Comment: You shouldn't run XAMPP on production. It is supposed to be used in development (or local) environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an server with Windows Server, them , why you not use IIS + PHP?.
have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php).

But if you still want to use apache2 + php + mysql in Windows, maybe, you should have a look to use [docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

Also, instead to use apache2 or IIS, you can use [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html).

There's a lot of solutions for that, but, personally, I use xaamp for development in my personal pc, not for deployment of apps and websites in server's.

Hope this information works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022!

XAMPP now supports 64-bit

Download [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)