# From Local to Live, which files to edit - Laravel

Tags: laravel, local

strangely I have never programmed locally, I am a beginner but unfortunately I have always created my little scripts directly live. I am using Laravel with Xampp, but now I would like to put my script online.

My question is, what files do I need to edit to make it effective online? At the moment I edit the .env file locally to connect to the database, but is it the same even if I put it online?

Thanks

Comment: A good starting point https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7eSJCevo4c you can even refer to this.

Comment: So, however, launching it online simply by changing the connection data in the .env file is not a safe and correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some basic information: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation and https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment

In general, to have a site in production (Laravel or not) it is better to manage your code with git (through Github, Gilab, etc.) 
to have a clean version management (the alternative is to use Ftp trought Cpanel, ...).

If you are a beginner, you can go to https://forge.laravel.com/ which is a portal that greatly facilitates the production of a Laravel project.

Otherwise, a generic hosting is better that has the possibility to connect via ssh, in order to easily execute the commands 
(composer install, php artisan, ...).

You can do many optimizations in production (I leave out the ones on the .env file you know):

When you do maintenance on the site it is always best to disable it first(status 503):

`php artisan down`

Upload the latest version of the code from the git repository:

`git pull`

Clean the item cache on the server:

`php artisan cache:clear`

Clean the route cache and recreate it (to do if there is no static code in web.php, but only references to code in the controller):

```
php artisan route:clear 
php artisan route:cache
```

Clean and optimize the config file (reduces the number of files to be read from ten to one):

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

Clean up expired passwords and reset tokens (clean up tokens when a user requests a password reset):

`php artisan auth:clear-resets`

Recreate the framework classes or update the application:

`composer dump-autoload` or `composer install`

Activate the site:

`php artisan up`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But let me explain better, I developed this script with laravel via Xampp virtual machine. Now I want to install it in a shared hosting, I was wondering if to connect it to the database it is sufficient to modify the .env file in the field about the database? I have already done a test and it is online, but my concern is that maybe this procedure is not entirely correct and safe.

Shouldn't I edit the file inside config/database.php instead of .env?

Comment: To configure the db, it is okay to use only the .env file (the config/database reference fetches the information from the .env file, unless you have modified config/database in another way). I make you aware that going into production with Xampp is not safe for other reasons (see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297731/why-is-xampp-not-suited-for-production), but I don't know your reasons ;-). Un saluto in italiano dalla svizzera italiana :-)

Comment: Ciao, e grazie mille per la tua risposta. I rightly use XAMPP only to develop it locally, but once finished I unload the package and upload the files to my hosting space. Excuse me ignorance, but is it insecure even so? I don't understand why, in the end I only used Xampp as a virtual environment for the initial development.

Comment: If you've only used xampp for local development, there's no problem.

Sorry for misunderstanding the question. In production make sure you have the parameters in the .ENV file:
```APP_ENV = production``` and
```APP_DEBUG = false```
.
Consider what is written in the post to improve site performance. Buon lavoro!